# With animated transform,onLayout cannot be triggered

Tags: react-native

My codes render a red square and moved using PanResponder.After release pan ,it move by animation transform.
But onLayout() does not trigger when I drag the square.
I want to get the square location anytime even in animating.
What is the problem?

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Animated.View
      style={[
        styles.box,
        {
          transform: [
            { translateX: this._animatedValue.x },
            { translateY: this._animatedValue.y },
          ],
          backgroundColor: 'red'
        },
      ]}
      {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
      onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => { console.log(nativeEvent.layout) }}
    />
  </View>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the current position at any time, and you're using a PanResponder to move track the user's touch while they move the square, I would suggest using a listener on your `Animated.event()` that I'm assuming you're passing to your `onPanResponderMove` handler.

It would look something like

```
Animated.event([null, {dx: this._animatedValue.x, dy: this._animatedValue.y}], {
  listener: ({nativeEvent}) => {
    //nativeEvent has your x and y position in it
  }
})
```

Here's the React Native docs on [Animated.event()](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#event), which have an example showing how to use it in a PanResponder, though they're only tracking on the X direction.