# React native on layout change (listen view position)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I want to listen the position of a view I am moving with a pan responder. I am using the onLayout prop to get the width, height, x and y positions, but it only runs when the first render. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Animated,
  PanResponder,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";

const WINDOW_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("window").height;

export default function Cropper({ photo }) {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2); // Use in future

  const pan = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;

  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, { dy: pan.y }]),
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        pan.flattenOffset();
      },
    })
  ).current;

 const onLayout = (event) => {
    const {
      nativeEvent: { layout },
    } = event;

    // Recalculate top and buttom views' height (setNativeProps)
  };

  const panStyle = {
    transform: pan.getTranslateTransform(),
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.blurView} />
      <Animated.View
        onLayout={(event) => onLayout(event)}
        {...panResponder.panHandlers}
        style={[
          styles.cropper,
          panStyle,
          {
            height: height,
          },
        ]}
      />
      <View style={styles.blurView} />
      <View style={styles.bottomButtonsContainer}></View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  blurView: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .9)",
  },
  cropper: {
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  bottomButtonsContainer: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "100%",
    height: 120,
  },
});
```

What I am trying to do is get the middle view position when the user moves it, and then recalculate the top and buttom views' height.

Answer (score 1):

if you're pulling in onLayout as a prop
`export default function Cropper({ photo }) {` should look like `export default function Cropper({ photo, onLayout }) {`

Otherwise, I agree with the response saying you likely need to declare `onLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot `const` for your `onLayout`.

I've tried your code on [snack expo](https://snack.expo.io/Chc3LHgWG) i can get console.logs when moving the red view

Comment: Yeah that's true, but I still have the same problem. It only runs when component mounts for first time. What I want is to move the middle view with the pan responder and then to automatically get the new view position.

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

OnLayout method not being triggerd on an Animated.View with a custom PanResponder passed in. when the Animated.View is moved using style transformations.

Solution(full code snippet is at the bottom):

Adding a additional listener to the `onPanResponderMove` method on the `PanResponder` that can trigger what ever method that is needed with the move event information.

```
onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, { dy: pan.y }], {listener: ({nativeEvent}) => {onSquareMoved(nativeEvent)}}),

const onSquareMoved = (event) => {
  console.log('square moved changes')
}
```

In order to call a method everytime the panResponder moves, we add a listner that listens to the event and calls the `onSquareXChanged` method - which is a renamed version of `onLayout`.

I've added a full snack that calls a method everytime the square moves, you can find it here:
https://snack.expo.io/@m4qr/spunky-soda

It uses code from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51275196/with-animated-transform-onlayout-cannot-be-triggered) provided by [@ajthyng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5927840/ajthyng). 
When running your version of the snack, I was getting the onLayout to fire only on first render and not when moving the squre. Combining the result of the debugging and the response on the following github issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28775, it seems that onLayout does not get triggered when style transformation values are changed in an Animated.View.

If your componenet inside of the `Animated.View` is a more complex one, or the animation required is heavier in terms of calculations, you might stumble upon performance issues. If you are intrested in adding more complex animation effects without losing performance, I'd recommend you look into the Reanimated 2 library which is currently in Alpha.
The library allows you to declare logic for animations that will later on be executed on its own thread as it levereges the worklet feature to allow running animation logic on it's own thread while maintaing 60 fps.

There is a great video by William Candillon exploring the new syntax of the library with an example similar to the snack in the question above:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=471&v=e5ALKoP1m-k&feature=emb_title

please let me know if there is anything further questions in regards to this.

Full example of working code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Animated,
  PanResponder,
  Dimensions,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";

const WINDOW_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("window").height;

export default function Cropper({ photo }) {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(WINDOW_HEIGHT / 2); // Use in future

  const pan = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;

  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, { dy: pan.y }],
        {listener: ({nativeEvent}) => onSquareMoved(nativeEvent)}}),
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        pan.flattenOffset();
      },
    })
  ).current;

  const onSquareMoved = (event) => {
    console.log('square was moved')
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.blurView} />
      <Animated.View
        onLayout={(event) => onLayout(event)}
        {...panResponder.panHandlers}
        style={[
          styles.cropper,
          panStyle,
          {
            height: height,
          },
        ]}
      />
      <View style={styles.blurView} />
      <View style={styles.bottomButtonsContainer}></View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  blurView: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .9)",
  },
  cropper: {
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  bottomButtonsContainer: {
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 0,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "100%",
    height: 120,
  },
});
```